# Sass for loop through td using ::before selector

Tags: css, sass

I am fairly new to sass and having some trouble getting the **::before** notation to work in a **@for loop**.

I have a table row with six **td** elements.

```
  <tr> 
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td data-th="Entered"></td>
      <td data-th="Location"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
```

Responsively I have changed my table to a list and would like add the **data-th** to my list when I am a mobile view.

I was hoping that my for loop implementation like so would work

```
@for $i from 3 to 5 {
  td::before(#{$i}) {
    /* The middle element */
    content: attr(data-th)": ";
  }
}
```

However, I am not able to see any change.

I tested the syntax with concept with background color on an nth child and it worked

```
@for $i from 3 to 5 {
  td:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    /* The middle element */
    background: red;
  }
}
```

Also I can get it to work by simply doing

```
td {

      &:before { content: attr(data-th)": " }

}
```

However that approach adds the colon to every td.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add **before** after identifying the nth-child. Having **nth-child** seems to be required.

```
@for $i from 3 to 5 {
   td:nth-child(#{$i}):before {
   /* The middle element */
      content: attr(data-th)": ";
   }
}
```